# Вырезать подстроку, зная начало и конец строки

Tags: php, preg_replace

На сайте появился какой-то вирь, найти его не получается никак. Но я думал, возможно, получится вырезать все от `<script...` до `</script>` включительно.

Нижеприведенные скрипты появляются в описаниях товаров и не всегда выглядят в таком виде.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать функцию по поиску от `<script...` до `</script>` включительно.

```
<div id="__tbSetup"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure-content-delivery.com/mware-detection/index.php?d=www.fotoshans.ru&amp;c=mwareDetect.returned"></script>

<script src="https://cdncache-a.akamaihd.net/loaders/1998/l.js?aoi=1311798366&amp;pid=1998&amp;zoneid=584255&amp;ext=SelectionLinks" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://secure-content-delivery.com/data.js.php?i={33C7B82D-FB04-4EA2-BDF3-C7FC7E698574}&amp;d=2013-7-30&amp;s=http://www.fotoshans.ru/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="__changoScript">var __chd__ = {'aid':11079,'chaid':'www_objectify_ca'};(function() { var c = document.createElement('script'); c.type = 'text/javascript'; c.async = true;c.src = ( 'https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://z': 'http://p') + '.chango.com/static/c.js'; var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(c, s);})();</script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="__simpliScript" src="http://i.simpli.fi/dpx.js?cid=3065&amp;m=0"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" id="__tweakbarScript" async="" src="https://extfeed.net/252d761d3e.js"></script>

<script src="http://js.bunchofads.com/s/flyinV1.js?pid=1517182&amp;freq_amount=1&amp;freq_period=24&amp;size=720&amp;offset=0&amp;buffer=50&amp;domainad=servedby.bunchofads.com" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <img width="1" height="1" style="visibility: hidden;" src="https://secure-content-delivery.com/ads/impression.php?i=%7B33C7B82D-FB04-4EA2-BDF3-C7FC7E698574%7D&amp;c=overlay&amp;lm=1408009878342" class="yzguyxmefgnfydhaictf zdmhqmdaqsajalghhtbq"  /> 
<script src="http://static.webprotectapp00.webprotectapp.com/partnerconfig/webprotect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.webprotectapp00.webprotectapp.com/apps/boot/boot-start.js?cb=8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.webprotectapp00.webprotectapp.com/apps/tv-classic/tv-classic-noboot-fg.js?cb=8"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.webprotectapp00.webprotectapp.com/apps/boot/boot-end.js?cb=8"></script>
```

Comment: @Tchort они не сами там появились, найди их и удали раз и навсегда.

Comment: Что это за зоопарк скриптов? Зачем так делать сайты?

Comment: Но снова появляются.

Comment: Может, правильнее начать с обновления системы?

Comment: Было уже, и техподдержка не может найти.

Comment: @Tchort наймите человека, который найдёт. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот заменит все скрипты на пустоту

```
$pattern = "~<script[^>]*>.*?</script>~si";
echo preg_replace($pattern, '', $text);
```

Только соглашусь со всеми выше, это очень плохая идея, лучше найти и удалить откуда берутся эти скрипты, так как в этом ничего хорошего нет и к хорошему не приведет.